# Set priority, due date while creating JIRA issue in python

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I want to create a jira issue in python. I know how to set the summary, issue type, description and project name but I can't find how to set priority, due date, environment and other fields.

This is what I know:

```
new_issue = jira.create_issue(project={'key': 'key'}, summary='New issue from jira-   python',   description='Look into this one', issuetype={'name': 'Bug'})
```

How can I set the other fields?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question is really about the Jira REST API itself, not the python client, since it is a [very thin layer](https://bitbucket.org/bspeakmon/jira-python/src/2145ac8dccc44868c6ea3df21b662574435a7c87/jira/client.py?at=master#cl-563).

According to the [Issue Fields in JIRA REST APIs](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Issue+Fields+in+JIRA+REST+APIs), `priority` can be set this way:

```
new_issue = jira.create_issue(project={'key': 'key'}, 
                              summary='New issue from jira-python',   
                              description='Look into this one', 
                              issuetype={'name': 'Bug'}, 
                              priority={'name': 'Major'})
```

As for the other fields, use the [REST API Browser (RAB)](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Using+the+REST+API+Browser) to inspect what other fields are available for filtering issues in a particular project (as you may know fields can vary from project to project).